# WP - Not saving all of the fields when saving data to ninja forms WP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

I am sending data to Ninja forms plugin to save in the WP, based on the example of how to send data from the frontend, that I could see on the [Ninja form docs](https://github.com/wpninjas/ninja-forms/blob/master/assets/js/front-end/controllers/submit.js). I have implemented that on my backend side built with `laravel/php`:

```
    $url = $this->postUrl . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'form_params' => [
            'security' => $this->getNonce(),
            'action' => 'nf_ajax_submit',
            'formData' => $request->formData,
        ]
    ]);
```

The `formData` looks like this:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "fields":[
       {"id":"1","value":"My Name"},
       {"id": "2","value":"myemail@email.com"},
       {"id":"3","value":"some message"}
   ]
}
```

Where `id` is an id of that `ninja form` in WP in my case `Contact form`, and each object in the fields array represents a field in the form. Id of that object is an id of that field.In my case id 1 is an id of name field, and id 2 is an id of email field, while id 3 is an id of message field. The data is being saved normally to `message` and `email` field as you can see on the image below, but not to the `name` field.

[image]

On checking the WP DB postmeta table I could see that fields are being saved as:

```
post_id  |  meta_key   |   meta_value

  341           field_2        myemail@email.com
  341           field_3        some message
  341           field_
```

So, the problem is that the `name` field is being saved as only `field_` with no value, why is there a problem when the other fields are being saved as they should?
I have also tried with sending the data with key value pairs like this:

```
{
 "id":"1",
 "fields":[
           {"key":"name","value":"My Name"},
           {"key": "email","value":"myemail@email.com"},         
           {"key":"message","value":"some message"}
 ]
}
```

But, then the `message` field is not being save. I have even tried the combination of having id for `message` field and `key` for `name` field, but then email field was not being saved. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have edited the question and would like it to be reopened